# AS3 multiple starling custom event dispatcher error

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am having an issue with custom events when I have more than 1.

Currently I have 2 custom events:

1. Navigation event
2. Friend action event

They are both pretty much the same as:

```
package events
{
import starling.events.Event;

public class NavigationEvent extends Event
{
    public static const SHOWSCREEN:String = "";
    public var params:Object;

    public function NavigationEvent(type:String, _params:Object = null, bubbles:Boolean=false, data:Object=null)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, data);
        this.params = _params;
    }
}
}
```

however the other is

```
public class FriendActionEvent extends Event
```

on the main class I have 2 listeners

```
this.addEventListener(events.NavigationEvent.SHOWSCREEN, onNavigationScreen);
this.addEventListener(events.FriendActionEvent.ACTION, onFriendAction);
```

and the methods however when I add the second listener I get the error

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert events::NavigationEvent@fe5ee21 to events.FriendActionEvent.
```

so I am guessing there is an issue with 2 custom events but unsure how to work around it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `onNavigationScreen` is taking `FriendActionEvent` in parameter (possibly a case of bad copy-paste from the other event handler).

Comment: and empty string as the name of event can lead to such error, in case both custom events has the same empty name )

Comment: So should I rename all the parameters to something unique? I will try anyway

Comment: Empty string was the issue.